# To get package linuxdcpp

Tags: software-installation

I was trying to install Linux dc++ in my Ubuntu 14.04 using terminal. But the following was shown in terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

Package linuxdcpp is not available, but is referred to by another package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linuxdcpp' has no installation candidate
```

What should I do to install Linuxdc ++?

Comment: Did you enable the universe repository? see [How do I enable the “Universe” repository?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 1):

`linuxdcpp` is founded in universe repository, so first enable it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

then run those commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install linuxdcpp
```

Comment: I can understand that you want to reach the 20,000 points as soon as possible. But the quality of your answers should not suffer. **;)**

Comment: @A.B. It was just missing some parts, it's even cached in my browser, and for reputation , i don't care whether 20000 more or less, I'm here just to learn and help when I can

Answer (score 0):

As you can take from the [Ubuntu Apps entry](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linuxdcpp/), the package has only been released up to 13.10 yet.

You can, however, try to get it to work by downloading (and modifying, if necesary) a version for an older release. For this, download the latest version for your architecture from here:

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/linuxdcpp/

As far as I can see, the latest version is 1.1.0-1ubuntu2. Download the Debian package (`.deb` extension) for your architecture. No open it with the archive manager and navigate to the file `DEBIAN/control`. In there, you'll find a line containing the package dependencies.

As you can see, each dependency has it's version prefixed with `>=`, so you can install it, even if later versions of the dependencies are installed instead.

Simply install the package using

```
sudo dpkg -i linuxdcpp*.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Should a dependency not be available either, get them the same way you did before. Afterwards run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

to finish the installation of packages with dependency problems.

Comment: Hmm... it seems to be available in my 14.04 distribution, and also according to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linuxdcpp

Comment: Then try Maythux's answer.